# How to hide bullets from AMChart version3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I am working with AMChart version3. I need to hide the bullets based on value. But somehow nothing work. Please help me to hide the bullets. Below is my code.

Basically i want to hide if percentage value is zero. But it show all.

```
  function drawChart(chartData) {

        chartData.forEach(obj => {
            obj.height = parseFloat(obj.height);
        });

        const highestError = Math.max(...chartData.map(obj => obj.percentage));
        const lowestError = Math.min(...chartData.map(obj => obj.percentage));
        const maxAbsoluteError = Math.max(Math.abs(highestError), Math.abs(lowestError));
        const buffer = 4; // Adjust the buffer value as needed
        const yAxisMinimum = -Math.ceil((maxAbsoluteError + buffer) / 5) * 5;
        const yAxisMaximum = Math.ceil((maxAbsoluteError + buffer) / 5) * 5;
        AmCharts.makeChart("atg-calibration-report-chart", {
            "theme": "none",
            "type": "serial",
            "dataProvider": chartData,
            "valueAxes": [{
                "position": "left",
                "title": "",
                "minimum": yAxisMinimum,
                "maximum": yAxisMaximum,
                "integersOnly": true,
                "axisAlpha": 0,
                "labelFunction": function(value) {
                    return value.toString() + '%';
                }
            }],
            "graphs": [{
                "type": "line",
                "valueField": "percentage",
                "bullet": "round",
                "bulletSize": 8, // Adjust bullet size as needed
                "balloonText": "[[category]] meter: <b>[[value]]%</b>",
                "lineAlpha": 0, // Set lineAlpha to 0 to hide the line
                "lineThickness": 0, // Set lineThickness to 0 to hide the line between the dots
                "listeners": [{
                    "event": "drawn",
                    "method": function(event) {
                        console.log('sdksdjskjkjk')
                        if (event.dataItem.dataContext.percentage === 0 || event.dataItem.dataContext.percentage === null) {
                            event.event.target.hideBullet();
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }],
            "categoryField": "height",
            "categoryAxis": {
                "autoGridCount": false, // Disable automatic grid count calculation
                "gridCount": 11, // Set the desired number of grid lines
                "gridPosition": "start", // Position the grid lines at the beginning of each category
                "labelFunction": function(valueText, serialDataItem, categoryAxis) {
                    // Custom label function to format decimal values as integers
                    return Math.round(parseFloat(valueText)).toString();
                },
                "maximum": 10 // Set the maximum value for the category axis
            },
            "export": {
                "enabled": true
            }
        });
    }
```

Any solution appeciated